# How to construct a ndarray from a numpy array? python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

I can't seem to convert it into an `ndarray` in numpy, i've read http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html but it didn't show me how i can convert my input data as shown below into an `ndarray`.

**How to construct a ndarray from a numpy array or a list of integer lists?**
**What's the difference between ndarray and array?** I could just use an `array` type right?

I have a list of integer counts like this

```
[[1, 2, 4, 1, 5],
 [6, 0, 0, 0, 2],
 [0, 0, 0, 1, 0]]
```

And i manage to use this code to create a `np.array` as shown in http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html#numpy.array

```
import numpy as np
x = [[1, 2, 4, 1, 5],
 [6, 0, 0, 0, 2],
 [0, 0, 0, 1, 0]]
print np.array(x)
```

[out]:

```
[[1 2 4 1 5]
 [6 0 0 0 2]
 [0 0 0 1 0]]
```

But I can't change it into a `np.ndarray` with this code:

```
import numpy as np
x = [[1, 2, 4, 1, 5],
[6, 0, 0, 0, 2],
[0, 0, 0, 1, 0]]
print np.ndarray(x)
```

I got an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/alvas/workspace/sklearntut/test.py", line 7, in <module>
    print np.ndarray(x)
TypeError: an integer is required
```

**How do I create a np.ndarray with the list of integer counts i've got?** What integer is the TypeError talking about?

Comment: there is no difference between ndarray and array.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

An `ndarray` *is* a NumPy array.

```
>>> x = np.array([1, 2, 3])
>>> type(x)
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

The difference between `np.ndarray` and `np.array` is that the former is the actual type, while the latter is a flexible shorthand function for constructing arrays from data in other formats. The `TypeError` comes your use of `np.array` arguments to `np.ndarray`, which takes completely different arguments (see docstrings).

Answer (score 10):

Though the accepted response is correct, that didn't help me actually create a 1-dimensional array of arrays.

As this thread is the first answer at Google, I post my work around, even if it isn't elegant solution (please don't hesitate to point one out to me):

```
import numpy as np

# Create example array
initial_array = np.ones(shape = (2,2))

# Create array of arrays
array_of_arrays = np.ndarray(shape = (1,), dtype = "object")
array_of_arrays[0] = initial_array
```

Be aware that `array_of_arrays` is in this case mutable, i.e. changing `initial_array` automatically changes `array_of_arrays` .

Comment: There is another way to one more dimension, you can use `numpy.expand_dims`, example: `np.expand_dims(initial_array, axis=0)`

Comment: So why didn't `np.ndarray(x)` work? Both np.ndarray and np.array's first parameter is shape.

Answer (score 2):

I will combine the accepted solution with the fixed code.
As said in the accepted solution, an `ndarray` *is* a NumPy `array`.

This essentially means that you should use `np.array` when constructing an ndarray from a list of lists, a list of tuples, a tuple of lists...

Fixed code fragment:

```
import numpy as np
x = [[1, 2, 4, 1, 5],
[6, 0, 0, 0, 2],
[0, 0, 0, 1, 0]]

# The difference: we call np.array
print np.array(x)
```

Hope this will help others out as this is the first Google answer.